# howto install Joomla 2.5 on root on ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: home-server

Can you please do show me how to install joomla on /var/www/ (root) folder
I don't want /var/www/joomla and I think I am stuck with how to create permission and too afraid to make writable to public.
Can you do step by step please....

Answer (score 0):

http://www.allaboutlinux.eu/joomla-2-5-3-on-ubuntu/4/

**How to install Joomla 2.5.3 on Ubuntu**

Comment: The link you gave is for version 11 not 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't allow until you are logged in as super user.
To install joomla in it login as super user and try to install.

Answer (score 0):

Well, download your joomla version from here : http://www.joomla.org/download.html
then go to the terminal and do `sudo unzip pathtojoomla.zip -d /var/www`
this will create a folder in the `/var/www` try extract files and directories from this folder and put them directly into `/var/www` (use `sudo nautilus /var/www` to access the /var/www using the nautilus browser)
for the permissions use 755 for directories and 644 for the files use `chmod` to set permissions.